# pentaho CE server 4.8 on OS X 10.8, jdk 1.7, tomcat starts, pentaho doesn't

Tags: tomcat, osx-mountain-lion, pentaho

I have downloaded the embedded pentaho server ... this should start without any database, I think (it did so on Windows).

I therefore do not have any jdbc libraries installed in tomcat ... is this a fatal error?

I have latest JDK on OS X 10.8.3 
javac 1.7.0_25 and the JRE is this version to (ie /usr/bin/java is symlinked correctly)

the tomcat home page (localhost:8080) says "resource not available"

I haven't used tomcat before and I'm not finding the logfiles very helpful.

The pentaho log says:

2013-07-15 10:15:08,088 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2013-07-15 10:15:08,194 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed

catalina.out has some specific errors:

```
10:15:08,088 ERROR [JDBCExceptionReporter] java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
10:15:08,194 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChainProxy' defined in file [/Users/tim/pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
```

Error creating bean with name 'authenticationProcessingFilter' defined in file [/Users/tim/pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in file [/Users/tim/pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'daoAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoAuthenticationProvider' defined in file [/Users/tim/pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in file [/Users/tim/pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userRoleDao' while setting bean property 'userRoleDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRoleDao' defined in file [/Users/tim/pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in file [/Users/tim/pentaho/biserver-ce-4.8.0-stable/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/applicationContext-spring-security-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level

Comment: it does use an embedded db (datasource=hibernate/quartz) under the covers, so there should at least be a hsql driver, but that should be in the pentaho webapp already. However given you have a connection refused message I would check the hibernate conf.

Comment: I think you are onto something.

Comment: I think you are onto something. When I run biserver-ce/data/start_hypersonic.sh, I can see lots of error messages, a completely different output to when I run start_hypersonic.bat on my Windows install. The first error is could not load properties from file. Then I get an exception invalid schema name: SYSTEM_SCHEMA. Then lots of errors, ending in 
[Server@4769baee]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @4769baee,5,main]]: Shutting down because there are no open databases
[Server@4769baee]: Initiating shutdown sequence..
http://pastebin.com/aUhvrr71

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue on OSX Mavericks with Pentaho CE 5.1.

Turns out I needed to specifically add the name of my Mac to /etc/hosts. I found my hostname by running 'hostname' in the terminal.

I added this entry in /etc/hosts.

127.0.0.1    MacbookName

After ensuring java processes were stopped, then running sh start-pentaho.sh worked, loading successfully, rather than the 404 page with 'Resource not Found'.